# Transform datetime in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I'm receiving this error:

```
Could not parse 'event_date' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]
```

from BigQuery when I'm trying to insert a row.

This is my code:

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY, 'roas-164016')
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(BQ_LOGS_DATASET_NAME)
table = dataset.table(BQ_EMAIL_SENDS_TABLE_NAME)

data = {}
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data['send_id'] = 'test'
data['uid'] = 'test'
data['account_id'] = 'test'
data['subaccount_id'] = 'test'
data['event_id'] = 'test'
data['event_date'] = now
data['html_content'] = 'test'
data['campaign_name'] = 'test'
data['subject'] = 'test'
data['send_type'] = 'test'

json_data = json.dumps(data)

data =  json.loads(json_data)
table.reload()

rows = [data]
errors = table.insert_data(rows)
```

How can I fix the date formatting?

Comment: @cricket_007 the only impact I see in loading and dumping is that it converts the strings to unicode... certainly not the cleanest approach, though

Comment: I'm not familiar with BigQuery, so this may be a silly question -- does it assume your columns come in a specific order?

Comment: rows (list of tuples) – Row data to be inserted. Each tuple should contain data for each schema field on the current table and in the same order as the schema fields.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If that's literally what you need.

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M[:%S[.%f]]")
```

More likely, the square brackets indicate optional parts. So:

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

or

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: If it's optional, then the question already has the right format

Comment: so just curious - what actually was the problem? accepted answer has (looks like) nothing new to compare with question :o) can you please shed light here?

Answer (score -6):

format your date into this YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
meaning the month day hour minutes and second should be in two digits format.

sample:

**2018-02-16 04:39:05 Correct**

*2018-2-16 4:39:5 wrong*

Happy coding!